# few questions regarding ufw firewall

Tags: firewall, ufw

I recently notice some increase on my raspberry and since I am on a limited data cap. I thought using UFW to block incoming traffic can help alleviate this problem while I figure out the reason for the high download.

however there is few questions.
if I block incoming, is it possible to allow only one script to be able to download? will this prevent the pi from connecting to NTP servers to get the time?

how about if I want to use apt-get to download or update something?
is there a way to be more in control to allow some specif domains to download from? and maybe upload to also?